# Dynamically selecting map Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have so far created the query:

```
query = from page in "wagtailcore_page",
      where: page.url_path == ^url_path,
      join: h in ^table_name,
      where: h.page_ptr_id == page.id
```

I now would like to dynamically select properties on `h`

For example if I pass in `[:body, :footer]` I would like to run:

```
query = from [_page, h] in query,
      select: %{body: h.body, footer: h.footer}
```

I found [Ecto.Query.API.map](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) which looks like it could be used in the solution to this problem.

But when I run:

```
from [_page, h] in query, select: EctoApi.map(h, [:body])
```

I get the error:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `EctoApi.map(h, [:alphatext])` is not a valid query expression
```

According to the `IMPORTANT` message at the bottom of the [`map` documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#map/2) we have to include the foreign keys used in the relationship when performing the join which we are not doing, but I don't know how to do this type of `assoc` for the type of dynamic join which we are doing

Comment: Does this work: `from [_page, h] in query, select: map(h, [:body, :footer])`?

Comment: No I get: `** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) map(h, [:body, :footer]) is not a valid query expression`

Comment: Actually, It worked! Fab, thanks @dogbert

Comment: Since it worked, maybe it makes sense to upgrade the comment into an answer. If you like I can do it for you.

Comment: That would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` can be used without importing anything. The actual function is implemented inside Ecto, `Ecto.Query.API.map/2` is just for documentation purposes. The following should work:

```
from [_page, h] in query, select: map(h, [:body, :footer])
```